# External login info is null for OWIN SSO and error=access_denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, owin

I am implementing SSO. When ExternalLogin method is called SSo page opens, I enter credentials and it goes to call back action ExternalLoginCallback. However, loginInfo is null in the code below.I also get error=access_denied in URl.

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```